# How can an array contain different objects as elements?

Tags: c#, c++, object

How can an array or linked list contain different objects as elements? How can this be accomplished in C# or C++?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: why don't you create list of `object` in C#? In C++ you can always use array or stl `vector` of `void*` and put anything into it. But the exact answer will depend upon your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way an array can contain different classes of objects is if they all have a common base, and the array is declared to contain that common base. For example, you could have 3 classes like this:

```
class MyBase {
    public int SomeParameter { get; set; }
}

class MyFirstChild : MyBase {
    public int SomeOtherParameter { get; set; }
}

class MySecondChild : MyBase {
    public int SomeOtherParameter { get; set; }
}
```

And your array would be declared like this:

```
MyBase[] myArray = new MyBase[3];
```

Now you can put different objects of type `MyBase` or its children into this array, like this:

```
myArray[0] = new MyBase();
myArray[1] = new MyFirstChild();
myArray[2] = new MySecondChild();
```

The same would work if all of them would implement some interface instead of inheriting from  `MyBase`.

Comment: You beat me to it, ill remove my answer

Comment: Why don't you leave yours? Who knows which one better fits the OP.

Comment: The question still makes no sense whatever answer the OP choose.It is not specified what "different objects" means.

Comment: @DanielGabriel could you explain me, what is the need of inheritance in this... thanks in advance

Comment: Inheritance is there to demonstrate how you can have "different objects", since that's what the question is asking.

Answer (score 3):

Well using c# you could declare an interface, with both types implementing the interface:

```
public interface IType
{} 

public class Thing : IType
{} 

public class Thing2 : IType
{} 


List<IType> list = new List<IType>();

list.Add(new Thing1());
list.Add(new Thing2());
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, it can't. However, it can contain:

- Pointers to different objects with a common base class. If you want the container to manage the lifetime of these objects (as it would if it contained them directly), then store smart pointers.
- Discriminated union or similar variant types. The Boost libraries provide `variant` (a union of a statically specified set of types) and `any` (a polymorphic wrapper to hold any type) for this.

I know nothing about C#, but I imagine you could do something similar to these.

Answer (score 0):

use an array of void pointers

some thing like void* ptr [];